# bingmaps direction task getting latitude/longitude wrong on windows phone 8 device

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I'm making an app that gets an online xml, saves it on the isolated storage and then loads it on the device. I get as string the latitude and longitude of each node on that xml and then save it on a var using a Double.Parse. When BingMapsDirectionTask runs on the Windows Phone 8/8.1 emulator, it gets lat and long correctly like this (22.002020,32.923293) and shows that location. When I'm running the same code on my windows phone 8 device, it gets lat and long wrong like this (22002020.0,32923293.0) and throws an out of range exception. Why is that?

Furthermore another question about BingMapsDirectionTask. With this someone can filter his location and find, near him, restaurants and other places of interest. Is there a way I can filter these results and make it show my xml nodes that are near the users location ?

Comment: noone can help me ? I even hard coded latitude and longitude as strings and then parsed them as Doubles,long,singles,float,decimal on var and still the same problem. I even changed the cultureinfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The problem was that my phone obviously had different Culture info than the emulator.
Parsing the culture info of the wanted format was what it needed to be done.

 var latitude = Double.Parse(Latitude, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
 var longitude = Double.Parse(Longitude, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```